# Scatter an Array using MPI_Scatter

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm writing a code in which I have 4 processes. Process-0 reads 64 numbers(from number.txt). It then scatters this array to all the processes. For that I declared an array "arr[64]" which is common to all processes . Each process has to print 16 elements(Process0: 0-16, Process1:16-32 Process2:32-48 Process3:48-64) and compute the partial sum of their range. That's why I have: for(i=(rank*16);i<((rank*16)+16);i++).
I'm not able to print the correct values. Currently, only processes 0&1 are printing the correct values and computing the correct partial sum. Processes 2&3 are printing garbage values and hence, computing garbage partial sums. How can I fix this?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int size, rank,i,j,count=0,final_val;
    int sum=0;
    int total[4]={0,0,0,0};
    int arr[64];
    int num[64];
    //int *buff=NULL;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    
    if(rank==0)
    {
        
        //Read File:
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("number.txt" , "r");
        if(fp == NULL) 
        {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
        }
   
        while (!feof (fp))
            {  
            fscanf (fp, "%d", &i);  
            num[count]=i;
            count+=1;
            }
        fclose (fp);
        //buff = num;
        
    }

    MPI_Scatter(num,64, MPI_INT,arr,64, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
        for(i=(rank*16);i<((rank*16)+16);i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        printf("sum_%d: %d\n",rank,sum);
MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
```

Comment: Since the `num` sendbuffer has 64 elements and the communicator has 4 processes, sendcount and recvcount should be both `16`. The scattered data will be available on each task in `arr[0:31]`, so you can declare `int arr[16]`.

Comment: But I am required to send the entire arrays to all the processes that's why I set both buffers to 64. If I set the buffers to 16 then will all the processes receive the entire array?

Comment: if you want to send the entire array, then you want to use `MPI_Bcast()`

Comment: Ok, and can you please explain why each process will have its 16 elements in arr[0:31]?Did you mean arr[0:15]?

Comment: oops, I did mean to write `arr[0:15]`

Comment: Ok, and how does MPI divide the index ranges? How does process0 automatically get num[0:16], process1-num[16-32],process2-num[32-48],process3-num[48-64]? We don't specify that anywhere.

Comment: This is the textbook definition of `MPI_Scatter()` https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node72.html

Comment: Yes, its working now. Thanks!